# Webkit placeholder text jumps

Tags: input, webkit, placeholder

I have an `<input />` with a placeholder. The input is custom-designed, i. e. it has no borders, no outline, a custom height, custom width, custom background color, custom text color, and a custom font with a specific font-size and line-height. That font is imported using @font-face referencing a *.ttf-file.

The problem is that when focussing on the input field, the placeholder text jumps about 2-3px higher, only to jump back on blur.

Here the definition of the input field:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: SourceSansProExtraLight;
    src: url('../fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.ttf');
}

#search_input{

    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    width: 236px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    width: 224px; /* width (236) - padding-left */

    font-family: SourceSansProExtraLight;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #5e5e5e;

    height: 52px;

}
```

Here's a GIF demonstrating the issue:

[image: Placeholder Jump]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check that you have write any css for input:focus Selector that may cause the issue. if you don't write any css for input:focus, write css for that to fix the problem.

Comment: This helped me solve an issue where some text was jumping inside an input box.  I had defined some css that affected the outline on input:focus, and that was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

With input[type="text"] there is no Problem.
I have the Problem only with input[type="number"] if the height and line height is equal:

```
input[type="number"] {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px; 
}
```

but if I reduce the line height the effect disapears:

```
input[type="number"] {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome reserve space for caret.

The height of the line must be greater than the height of the font at 1.11 units (*on my system*).

Example:

```
font-size = 30px
line-height = 30px * 1.11 = round(33,3px) = 33px
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `outline-offset: 0` when the input has `:focus`. That fixed the jumping placeholder bug for me on WebKit. I was also setting `outline: none` and showing a custom `box-shadow`, which may be the cause.